# How to observe tasks that are not awaited due to failure in another awaited task in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I have this code:

```
var task1 = operation1();
var task2 = operation2();


var result1 = await task1;
var result2 = await task2;
```

I do also handle `UnobservedTaskException` (by logging it). The problem that I face is that after task1 fails and first await results in exception, task2 completes in an error and then I have a log entry that I do not want to see as I will already log the first exception and at that point all subsequent exceptions are of no interest to me.

So I am wondering if there is a way to do something so that all tasks are "ignored" in a way after I get an exception.

I know I can use `await Task.WhenAll`, but the downside is that I have to wait for all exceptions to happen, though I know for sure that after first task results in exception, I don't need to wait for the other task to complete as the whole operation already failed.

Another possible solution is to write try/catch and cancel all tasks, but that's a bit cumbersome.

P.S.
The example is simplified, I do have multiple tasks running like that. So I am looking for a generic solution that would work for any number of tasks

Comment: Ultimately, the moment that you *don't* immediately `await` something, you're into "concurrency" territory - presumably very intentionally here. Things are *going* to get a bit messy: that comes with the choice to go concurrent. If it was me, I'd make sure that `operation1()` and `operation2()` *can never fault* - i.e. they should do their own exception handling internally; if they need to report failure to the caller, they can do that via a *soft* error (in the returned value - an error-code property, for example)

Comment: That would be a lot of work to do through the whole stack as we do e.g. a lot of http calls async, so it's quite a lot of plumbing do it this way, but it's probably the safest, I just hoped there is some "silver bullet" in .Net for this. This is rather ordinary situation with async/await, but I guess Task.WhenAll is a standard way of solving it at some cost though

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Are `operation1` and `operation2` independent? How do you want to run them sequentially or in parallel?

Comment: They are independent and I do want to run them in parallel

Comment: If they are independent and they run in parallel then why do you want to suppress some failure? 1) Both can succeed 2) Both can fail 3) One of them can fail. If they are independent then observing only just one of them then the logs can mislead you. If they are coupled then cooperative cancellation would make more sense to me.

Comment: To make it clear, is the [`UnobservedTaskException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception) event handler the main mechanism for logging task-related exceptions in your application? Because if it's not, and if all the exceptions you log by using this mechanism are not interesting for you, then the solution seems clear: stop handling this event!

Comment: Well, I want to handle UnobservedTaskException to see some errors that happen due to other problems, like e.g. we forgot await somewhere or whatever other things happen that we have coded wrong. Regarding another question: the tasks are independent for each other, but when any of the fails, the top request fails, so it is of no interest to us that the other tasks fail as well, it's enough with one exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to `Task.WhenAll` you can use a progressive approach with `Task.WhenAny`.

When any of the Tasks finishes then you can examine the result and you can decide what to do next. (Please bear in mind that `Task.WhenAny` does not throw exception even it is awaited) The great thing about this approach is that you can easily add throttling (control the degree of parallelism) to this.

#### The basic implementation of progressive async for each

```cs
static async Task ProgressiveAsyncForEach(int degreeOfParallelism, params Task[] tasks)
{
    var toBeProcessedTasks = new HashSet<Task>();
    var remainingTasksEnumerator = tasks.GetEnumerator();

    void AddNextTask()
    {
        if (!remainingTasksEnumerator.MoveNext()) return;
        var nextTaskToProcess = (Task)remainingTasksEnumerator.Current;
        toBeProcessedTasks.Add(nextTaskToProcess);
    }

    //Initialize
    while (toBeProcessedTasks.Count < degreeOfParallelism)
    {
        AddNextTask();
    }

    while (toBeProcessedTasks.Count > 0)
    {
        var processedTask = await Task.WhenAny(toBeProcessedTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (!processedTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("One of the task has failed");
            //TODO: log first failed task
            //CONSIDER: cancel all the remaining tasks
            return;
        }

        toBeProcessedTasks.Remove(processedTask);
        AddNextTask();
    }
}
```

#### Sample usage

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await ProgressiveAsyncForEach(2, Faulty(), Fast(), Slow());
    Console.WriteLine("Application finished");
}

static async Task Slow()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Slow started");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Slow finished");
}

static async Task Fast()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fast started");
    await Task.Delay(500);
    Console.WriteLine("Fast finished");
}

static async Task Faulty()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Faulty started");
    await Task.Delay(700);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: `while (toBeProcessedTasks.Count < degreeOfParallelism)` - if we dont have enough tasks to fill up the condition we are dead.

Comment: @Digika Usually we have more tasks to do than the level of parallelism that we want to allow. But that case which was mentioned by you can be easily supported by altering the while condition.